# $ k^0-\bar{k^0} $ mixing and gauge boson propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I'm studying $ k^0-\bar{k^0} $ mixing from Cheng & Li's book "gauge_theory_of_elementary_particle_physics", page: 379 ..

I found that they consider the gauge boson propagator in the Feynman gauge, where $ i\Delta_{\mu\nu} = -i \frac{g_{\mu\nu}}{k^2-M^2_W} $ , but till my knowledge in this gauge the goldstone bosons remain in the theory, so why the contribution of the charged goldstone bosons for instance has not been taken into account in the calculation of the box diagram like $ W^\pm $ ?

Also if I calculate other process like $ b \to s~ l^+ l^-$ which gauge should i use for the gauge boson propagator to avoid goldstone bosons in the decay ?

Comment: No I don't think it's easier, I say why it didn't ever menstioned in the book that in Feynman gaude k0-k0 mxing has ghost contribution ? the question are their contribution too small so that neglected ? or canceled ? for instance $\mu \to e \gamma$ calculated in the same book and they taken all ghosts contribution in R- gauge .

Comment: All is in:  p 509, ξ=1.   Last comment.

Comment: I'm afraid , i don't get what you mean, for $\zeta=1$ the charged ghost propagator will be $\frac{i}{k^2-M^2_W}$

Comment: p. 512 ... not ghosts for fermions, but suppressed scalar (goldston) couplings. Try Barger and Phillipps for more detail.

Comment: @ Cosmas Zachos .. really thanks for your reply, but can you explain more please . Ok I saw in page 512 the coupling $(\phi^\pm~ p~ n) \sim m_{n/b} / M_W $ which of course so suppressed , but what did you mean about page 509 ?  in this page the propagator of $\phi$ scalars and the gauge bosons .

Comment: The propagators for the Ws and the scalars have the same denominator... so it's not as though the propagator of a scalar exchange would negate the effect of the vertex suppression....